# How to use function from a functions.php file in angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to retrieve users info by a function in `PHP` in my angular.

**angular code:**

```
$scope.users = $http({
  method: 'GET',
   url: 'functions.php/getUsers()'
  }).then(function(response){
   $scope.users = response.data;
  },function(reason){
   $scope.error = reason.data;
  });
}
```

where `getUsers()` is the function which is returning `json` data to the angular.

is there any other way to use functions in angular from a `PHP` files?

Answer (score 1):

> remember the `functions` can not be equal to our public variable, in this sample you have `$scope.users` as `function` and also you have that again equal to `response.data` (actually you miss the `function`)
>
> you can't read from files, you have to use api URL which return `json` to you

```
$scope.users = $http({
  method: 'GET',
   url: 'functions.php/getUsers()'
  }).then(function(response){
   $scope.users = response.data;
  },function(reason){
   $scope.error = reason.data;
  });
}
```

**change to**

```
$scope.getUsers = function(){
  //for example api url for your users is "http://localhost:8080/users"
  var api = "you api url";
  $http({method: 'GET', url: api}).then(function(response){
   $scope.users = response.data;
  },function(reason){
   $scope.error = reason.data;
  });
 }    
}
//request data
$scope.getUsers();
```

**OR use it directly without function**

```
//for example api url for your users is "http://localhost:8080/users"
var api = "you api url";
$http({method: 'GET', url: api}).then(function(response){
  $scope.users = response.data;
},function(reason){
  $scope.error = reason.data;
});
}
```

Comment: no where! the `PHP` files not related to your `js` files because you currently want to get data from your `api` so use it directly from your js.

Comment: Actually my `functions.php` file have many functions in which one of them is `getUsers()` which is returning users info. Now the task is i want the get the data from `getUsers()` function because every function return something. How to do that

Comment: ok so update your question with `functions.php -> getUsers()` function and let us see what you did in that.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call a PHP function in a JavaScript file in this way. You can do it by  following these steps:

1) create `get-users.php` file

```
<?php
    require 'functions.php';  

    echo getUsers();
?>
```

2) make the http request to the created file

```
$scope.users = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'your-website-url/get-users.php'
 }).then(function(response){
    $scope.users = response.data;
 },function(reason){
   $scope.error = reason.data;
 });
}
```

**Update**

if you have a lot of functions and don't want to create a file for every function. then you can do it like this:

1) create `all-functions.php` file

```
<?php

  require 'functions.php';

  if (function_exists($_GET['func'])) {
    echo call_user_func($_GET['func']);
  } else {
     echo "Error: function does not exist";
  }

  ?>
```

2) Update your angular code

```
 $scope.users = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'your-website-url/all-functions.php',
    data: {
        func: 'getusers' 
     }
 }).then(function(response){
    $scope.users = response.data;
 },function(reason){
   $scope.error = reason.data;
 });
}
```